# jquery .focus(func) doing process several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Puneet who created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G3vSK/

It seems that it doesn't work on Chrome Version 28

On Firefox (v22) the alert comes once, but you can't enter anything in the boxes

---

Another problem I can't solve:
This is my Javsacript-Code:

```
function updateFieldsetStyleAdjustment(){
    alert("update");
    $('fieldset').not('[data-style=\'none\']').find('input, select, textarea, button')  //find input-fields

        .focus(function(){
            alert("active: "+$(this).attr('id'));
        });
}
```

This function should add an onfocus-Handler to some input-fields on my site.
Whenever I focus an field to insert a value, it should be called.

My problem is that, when I focus an input-field, the function is called several times. The number of calls/alerts varies from 3 to 16 or more per focus-Event.

However, my field never looses focus.

I apply the onfocus-event 2 times (The "update"-alert appears twice), but this is normal.
(I don't add 16 onfocus-event listeners to the input-fields).

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Here's the HTML-snipped:

```
<fieldset id="fs_1" data-style="data" d class="">
    <legend>General Information</legend>

    <div class="lineWrapper inputTooltip" data-tooltippos="left">
        <label for="fs_1_form51f37d255fb35_name">Name</label>
        <span class="inputWrapper">
            <input type="text" id="fs_1_form51f37d255fb35_name" name="name" autofocus="" maxlength="40" tabindex="50">
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="lineWrapper inputTooltip" data-tooltippos="left">
        <label for="fs_1_form51f37d255fb35_ansprechperson">Ansprechperson</label>
        <span class="inputWrapper">
            <input type="text" id="fs_1_form51f37d255fb35_ansprechperson" name="ansprechperson" maxlength="40" tabindex="51">
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- ...more Wrappers with input-fields... -->
</fieldset>
<!-- ...more fieldsets... -->
```

**How I call it:**

1.) $(document).ready(function() { updateFieldsetStyleAdjustment(); });

2.) After every Ajax-Request I call it again (the input-fields are loaded via Ajax)

**unbind:**

When I put `$(this).unbind('focus');` inside my focus-eventhandler, it is triggered only once. But when I focus the same field again, it doesn't work anymore (as expected).

When I put `$('*').unbind('focus');` on the beginning of my `updateFieldsetStyleAdjustment()`-Function, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: can you also share the html and how `updateFieldsetStyleAdjustment` is invoked

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I have a hunch. I once bound a .fadeIn/Out to multiple selectors at once and every time I called it the animations would run for every selectors matched. Try removing everything but 'input' and see if it reduces the amount of the focus callbacks run.

Comment: @Ken This solution sounds as strange as my problem xD. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert() was the bug.
Realised that everything was working fine without the alert(). And the event was also only triggered once.

The alert always unfocused the input-field, and so a new alert was created.

I hate it, when my debugging-code is the only bug in the program.

Comment: I found your question because I had he same problem, saved me some time!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies here.
**After every Ajax-Request I call it again (the input-fields are loaded via Ajax).**

Try binding `focus` with only the new `fieldset` generated after ajax calls (try using [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function). Alternatively try

```
    $('fieldset').not('[data-style=\'none\']').find('input, select, textarea, button').unbind('focus');
 //unbind focus from previously binded dom elements.
```

and then call

```
updateFieldsetStyleAdjustment
```

Comment: First I thought about the same, but it isn't working. I call the update-function twice: document.ready (no fieldsets on the page), and on the first ajax-request. However, the event triggers up to 20 times.
And the number varies, even if I don't change anything.
I tried the unbind-method, but it didn't work

Comment: May be you can do away with first call to function. How many fieldsets are getting generated with ajax?
Also try 
'.focus(function(e){
            alert("active: "+$(this).attr('id'));
e.stopPropagation();
        });'

Comment: I have 4 Fieldsets, but I can load more dynamically. Now I removed all automatic calls, and made an input-button to call the function manually. Same effect.

Comment: well a better look at the ajax function will help in knowing what is happening. I tried replication of your Js code here http://jsfiddle.net/G3vSK
when calling the function only once after the generation of fieldsets is working fine. Please have a look. I did not implement the ajax part as I was unaware of it.

Comment: Wow. The fiddle you created doesn't work for me.  ## Browser Chrome v28: I have the exact same problem. ## Browser Firefox v22: It works, in except that I cant put anything in the input-Boxes (the cursor doesn't appear / I'm unfocused immediately)

Comment: Yeah. I get it now. Chrome and alert together caused the issue.